# Prevent horizontal scroll, overflow property isn't working

Tags: html, css

I am using very wide shapes as the background on my website (to create a certain visual effect) and am not able to prevent the horizontal scrolling. Is there any other way to achieve that besides the overflow property which doesn't seem to work for me? http://tinyurl.com/kahfjha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css `#contact-shape` and `#design-shape` Are `width:5000px` remove that and it works fine.

```
#design-shape {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e98e82;
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
height: 1040px;
top: 1200px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 6;
}

#contact-shape {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000;
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
height: 1460px;
top: 2757px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

**Update:** I changed the css a bit now its keeping the backgrounds in place as well.

Comment: I see. try adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to `body` as well. it works perfectly in chrome for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `overflow-x: hidden` instead of `overflow: hidden` on the body element and it will work:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```